# How to show with infinite loop this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code will show aaa ===> bbb ===> ccc ===> ddd for a single loop, i want to know how to show with infinite loop ?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fe0mkdf4/3/
```

..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".word").typed({strings:['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'], typeSpeed: 45,backSpeed: 30,backDelay: 5000});
});
$(window).load(function(){init();});
</script>
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
 $(".word").typed({strings:['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'], typeSpeed: 45,backSpeed: 30,backDelay: 5000,loop: true,loopCount: null});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `loop` and `loopCount` to options

```
$(".word").typed({
   strings:['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'],
   typeSpeed: 45,
   backSpeed: 30,
   backDelay: 5000,
   // loop
   loop: true,
   // null = infinite
   loopCount: null,
});
```